# Display sum of each element in a column using sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have simple data from database looks like this

```
ID   sid   targetbuttonname

1    ab23sve   Yes
2    ab23sve   Yes
3    ab23sve   Yes
4    ab23sve   Yes
5    z32b2367  no
6    zb23sve   no
7    pb23sve   Yes
```

I want to display the sum of `session`, the sum of `yes`, the sum of `no` using sql;

eg sum of `yes`  should be `5`  etc

I tried something like this

```
select sum(sid), count(targetbuttoname) as yes, count(targetbuttoname) as no from events
```

What is the right way to display what I want?

Comment: What is your expected result based on your example?

Comment: `'yes'` is a string.  Summation does not make sense on a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you have 5 yes , I meen the result should be 5 if its yes , if its `no` then its sum should be `2` etc hope u understand what I mean w

Comment: How about the sum of session?

Comment: @GenWan should be 7

Comment: @GordonLinoff your right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want to count these things.  So, I would guess:

```
select count(*) as num_rows,
       count(distinct sid) as num_sessions,
       sum( targetbuttonname = 'yes' ) as num_yes,
       sum( targetbuttonname = 'no' ) as num_no
from events;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5275540801c3aab2bee3683fb65afda4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: here is test from your solution jdoodle.com/a/1pHG   check it , not working

Answer (score 1):

if you want to count number of yes and no then you can use `case when`

```
  select  sum(case when targetbuttoname='yes' then 1 else 0 end) as yes,
  sum(case when targetbuttoname='no' then 1 else 0 end) as  no from events
```

Comment: I think you solution is good but you forgot to add sum of sid, but I tested your solution here https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1pHG